# Ember cli 0.1.15 Path or pattern "ember-data.js.map" did not match any files

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I just upgrade my ember cli project and now get this error when running ember server.

Path or pattern "ember-data.js.map" did not match any files

I noticed a post here but doesn't help my case

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2557

package

```
{
  "name": "cli",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for cli goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.2.0",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.0",
    "broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler": "^1.6.1",
    "ember-cli": "0.1.15",
    "ember-cli-6to5": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.3.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "0.0.7",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^0.6.0",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-less": "^1.0.5",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "1.0.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.14.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-select-2": "^1.1.1-beta1",
    "ember-validations": "2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "express": "^4.8.5",
    "glob": "^4.0.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the recommended upgrade steps and cleared the npm and bower cache?